# Поменять расположение блоков в друпале

Tags: drupal

Добрый день.
Никак не могу разобраться каким образом можно в друпале поменять расположение блоков.
Вот тут, на [сайте](http://nineteenfifteen.prototype-interactive.com/category/seasons/summer-2012) справа есть 2 блока: **PICK OF THE WEEK** и **Archives**.
Нашел в админке где их можно включать и отключать, просто в разделе блоки поменять ихнее местоположение на **none**.
Но как их можно местами поменять-то?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот по этому пути зайдите `/admin/structure/block`.

Там можно мышкой перетащить нужный блок выше или ниже, если взяться за крестик слева.

Comment: 404 у меня выдаётся по етому адресу :(  
  
однако, как я уже говорил я могу перемещать эти блоки по разным частям сайта, вот по етому пути: /admin/build/block    
и выглядит это так:  
https://dl.dropbox.com/u/38721261/%D0%9C%D1%83%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%80/blocks.png

Comment: Как вариант, можно через jQuery выдернуть нужный блок и вставить куда надо. Примерно так:
$('.block1').clone().insertAfter($('.block2'));
$('.block1').eq(0).remove();
А вообще, расположение блоков еще можно задать в шаблоне page.tpl.php например. Вообще странно, что нельзя поменять порядок, это какая версия drupal?